# Mongo in node.js add an $gte/$lt inside an $in or something similar

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I use MongoDB Node.js driver. My query looks like that :

```
   var query = {
        $and: [{
            "custom_date": {
                "$gte": minDateValue,
                "$lt": maxDateValue
            }
        }, {"doc_name": {"$in": file_type}}, {"sample_type": {"$in": sample_type}}, {"mission": {"$in": mission}}, {"snow_thickness": {"$in": snow_thickness}},{
            "depth_m": {
                "$gte": minDepthOut,
                "$lt": maxDepthOut
                // Or equal to "NA"
            }
        }]
    };
```

Everything works fine, but I woud like to add an $in or an $or to the field depth_m so this part of the query would be "$gte": minDepthOut,"$lt": maxDepthOut or equal to "NA" for exemple.

I mean the depth_m must be in the specified range or equal to "NA"

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`$or`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) query operator

```
{
  "$and": [
    { "custom_date": { "$gte": minDateValue, "$lt": maxDateValue }},
    { "doc_name": { "$in": file_type } },
    { "sample_type": { "$in": sample_type } },
    { "mission": { "$in": mission } },
    { "snow_thickness": { "$in": snow_thickness } },
    { "$or": [
      { "depth_m": {
        "$gte": minDepthOut,
        "$lt": maxDepthOut
      }},
      { "depth_m": "NA" }
    }]
  ]
}
```